# Render message after Ajax post from partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fancybox, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partail view that opens in fancybox. When i post the form i want to display a validationmessage in the partial view that shall be open in fancybox.

When i use my code i dont get the alert message and i get redirected to: http://domain.com/TextMessage does anyone know wye ?

The page i get redirected to doesent show it in fancybox, do i need to call it again on success?

**_SendSms**

```
$('#sendBtn').click(function () {

        var dataArray = $('form').serializeArray();
        var dataObj = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
            dataObj[dataArray[i].name] = dataArray[i].value;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TextMessage/Send",
            data: AddAntiForgeryToken({ salonId: dataObj['SalonId'], toNumber: dataObj['ToNumber'], message: dataObj['Message'] }),
            success: function (respons) {

                // Can't reach.
                alert("klar");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Render Form View:**

```
public PartialViewResult Index()
    {
        var salon = _customerManager.GetSalon();
        var smsViewModel = new SmsViewModel
                               {

                                   ToNumber = salon.MobileTel,
                                   Message = string.Format("Ni kommer vid första uppstarten av extreme bli frågade om uppgifter. \n Dessa kommer här: \n Databas: {0}.", salon.DatabaseName),
                                   DateSent = DateTime.MinValue,
                                   SentByUser = _securityManager.CurrentUser.Name,
                                   SalonId = salon.Id
                               };

        return PartialView("Partial_Views/_SendSms", smsViewModel);
    }
```

**Send method:**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Send(string salonId, string toNumber, string message)
    {
        var returnValue = false;

        try
        {
            using (var client = new SmsService.SMSServiceSoapClient("SMSServiceSoap"))
            {
                //client.SendSMSGeneric(int.Parse(salonId), "Itsperfect Software Europe AB", toNumber, message, 8);
            }

            returnValue = true;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error trying to get Salons withId", ex);
            returnValue = false;
        }

        return Json(new { success = returnValue }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**AddAntiforgeryToken function:**

```
function AddAntiForgeryToken(data) {
    data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    return data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not suppress default behavior of the button:

```
$('#sendBtn').click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of the handler here
}
```